# Going back to previous fragment not working correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

I am using a navigation drawer and when I select an item, it correctly replaces the previous fragment with the one I have selected, but if I open another one, and then click the back button, it goes to the previous activity instead of the previous fragment, what is wrong that it is doing this?

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment newFragment;
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            //Update
            newFragment = new UpdateFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
            break;
        case 1:
            //Maps
            newFragment = new TimetableFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
            break;
        case 2:
            //Timetables
            newFragment = new TimetableFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
            break;
        case 3:
            //Notes
            newFragment = new TimetableFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
            break;
        case 4:
            //About
            newFragment = new AboutFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
            break;
        case 5:
            //Settings
            newFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
            break;
    }
    //listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    //setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` method in `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the fragment in BackStack like :

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

## Edit :

To show the current fragment name in actionbar, you can get it on `onResume` of your FragmentActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    FragmentManager fragManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = this.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    // Fetch last fragment
    Fragment fragment = fragManager.getFragments().get(count>0?count-1:count);

    // Check with your possible Fragment class
    if( fragment instanceof OneFragment)
    {
        setTitle("OneFragment");
    }
    else if(fragment instanceof TwoFragment)
    {
        setTitle("TwoFragment");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: This is pretty good, although when I press the back button, the title of my activity does reflect the current fragment that has been loaded from the backStack?

Comment: @MysticMagic This is pretty good, although when I press the back button, the title of my activity does reflect the current fragment that has been loaded from the backStack?

Comment: Do you want to reflect the name ??

Comment: I want the toolbar title to change whenever the older fragment is loaded again. 

I usually do it with this
 **setTitle(navigationDrawerItems[position]);**

but that is inside the switch so it isn't being called. @SweetWisher

Comment: You can get current Fragment in `onResume` and accordingly set the title

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this, using onResume, in activity. Could you please provide a bit more detail? @SweetWisher

Comment: I'm getting some compatibility issues as it wants to use v4.Fragment manager here **Fragment fragment = fragManager.getFragments().get(count>0?count-1:count);**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66574/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-alan-gordon).

Answer (score -1):

You are adding null to the backstack -

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Replace this null with tag name of your fragment.

It will work.

Comment: Nop, you can set null to this method. Doesn't matter if it null.

Comment: As per the doc, for remembering the transaction we will add it to backstack - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Comment: It will add fragment to backstack if you set null here, also it will add fragment to backstack if you set string.