# Backstack android fragment navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

This is how I used navigation drawer to display Fragments:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment0();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Fragment4();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Fragment5();

                }

            default:
                break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);
            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
```

Suppose if the user navigates to **`Fragment 2-> Fragment 5-> Fragment3.`**

If the user clicks the **`back button`** I need to have the `descending order` and on each fragment I am displaying the `name` of the Fragment when he goes to that particular `fragment` ie:

**`Fragment 3-> Fragment 5-> Fragment2.`**

This is what I have tried:

**First Method:**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

**Second Method:**

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

I'm unable to get this working**(ie.. I'm unable to move it back to the fragment where I have come from**) and unable to display the name of the fragment based on the backstack

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399036/going-back-to-previous-fragment-not-working-correctly/27399288#27399288) can be helpful

Comment: @SweetWisherシ-I'm getting error at this line Fragment fragment = fragManager.getFragments().get(count>0?count-1:count); stating that  getFragments is undefined for Fragmentmanager

Comment: I think your backstack is working properly. You can navigate back same way to went. And if you want to get the stack count you can use getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() method

Comment: yes but how do I set the title as the title is not changing while clicking on the backbutton

Comment: You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` ie v4.Fragment

Comment: @SweetWisherシ-Yes using the same

Comment: for action bar tittle, in each fragment you can set getactionbar().settitle("screen name") on the onCreateView method.

Comment: when you backpress the fragments onCreateView method will be called

Comment: Ohk I am posting an answer. check it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation is working fine I guess and the issue you are facing is the tittle for which you can use

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        // Updating the action bar title
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Screen name");


        return v;
    }
}
```

in every fragment. And whenever you backpress the onCreateView method of fragmemt(the one which is poping from the backstack) gets called and the tittle will again set replacing the old tittle.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Handle back

You can use `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()` method in `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
         getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the fragment in BackStack like :

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

## 2. Display Name

To show the current fragment name in actionbar, you can get it on `onResume` of your Fragment :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ((FrgmentActivtiyName)getActivity).changeTitle("title");
}
```

Define a method which set the title in the actionbar in your FrgmentActivity:

```
public void changeTitle(String titleToSet) {
   // set title as titleToSet
}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: I dont think this is needed because he has all the fragments in the backstack able to show in the same order when navigate back. So no need to add or remove any fragment from the stack

Comment: @SweetWisherシ- What arun said is right. I'm able to show them but the problem is with the title.

Comment: what this statement says : *I'm unable to get this working **(ie.. I'm unable to move it back to the fragment where I have come from**) and unable to display the name of the fragment based on the backstack*. It says *You are **NOT** able to move back*

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In the activity which holds the fragments, override the onbackPressed() method by,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
         getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bhargav-here how do I get the positon of the fragment?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        menuList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        menuList.setSelection(position);
    }
```